# Iterator as boolean statements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I came across this code:

```
def myzip(*args):
    iters = map(iter, args)
    while iters:
        res = [next(i) for i in iters]
        yield tuple(res)
```

I'm unsure as to:

- Why the list comprehension doesn't need to catch a StopIteration
- how does `while iters` work as I've tried:

  ```
  x=[1,2]
  x=iter(x)
  if x: 
      print("Still True")
  next(x)
  next(x)
  if x: 
      print("Still True")
  ```

and it still prints `"Still True"` in both cases.

The author of the code also said because map returns a "one-shot iterable" in 3.X and "as soon as we’ve run the list comprehension inside the loop once, iters will be exhausted but still True(and res will be []) forever". He suggested to use `list(map(iters, args)` instead if we're using 3.X.

I'm unsure of how this change actually helps it to work as I thought that even if iterators are at the `StopIteration` point it still is `True` (based on what I tried earlier).

Edit:

The author gave this as an example

```
>>> list(myzip('abc', 'lmnop'))
[('a', 'l'), ('b', 'm'), ('c', 'n')]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several aspects to the question.

### python-2.x

The `map` returns a `list` and the `while iters` just makes sure that the code doesn't go into the loop in case there were no `*args` passed into the function. That's because an empty list is considered `False` and a not-empty list is considered `True`.

In case there are no `*args` it won't enter the loop and implicitly `return`s which then raises a `StopIteration`.

In case there is at least one argument the `while iters` is equivalent to `while True` and it relies on one of the iterators to raise a `StopIteration` after being exhausted. That StopIteration doesn't need to be catched (at least before Python 3.7) because **you want the `myzip` to stop if one iterable is exhausted**.

### python-3.x

In Python 3 `map` returns a `map` instance which will always considered `True` so the `while` loop is equivalent to `while True`.

However, there is one problem in python-3.x: After iterating over a `map` instance once it will be exhausted. In the first iteration (of the `while` loop) that works as expected, but in the next iteration `map` will be empty and it will just create an empty list:

```
>>> it = map(iter, ([1,2,3], [3,4,5]))
>>> [next(sub) for sub in it]
[1, 3]
>>> [next(sub) for sub in it]
[]
```

There is nothing that could raise a `StopIteration` anymore so it will go in an infinite loop and return empty `tuple`s forever. That''s also the reason you don't want to enter the `while` loop if the `iters`-list is empty!

It could be fixed (as stated) by using:

```
iters = list(map(iter, args))
```

### general observation

Just a note on how it would make more sense:

```
def myzip(*args):
    if not args:
        return
    iters = [iter(arg) for arg in args]  # or list(map(iter, args))
    while True:
        res = [next(i) for i in iters]
        yield tuple(res)
```

If you want the code to be python-3.7 compliant (thanks @Kevin for pointing this out) you explicitly need to catch the `StopIteration`s. For more informations refer to [PEP-479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/):

```
def myzip(*args):
    if not args:
        return
    iters = [iter(arg) for arg in args]  # or list(map(iter, args))
    while True:
        try:
            res = [next(i) for i in iters]
        except StopIteration:  
            # the StopIteration raised by next has to be catched in python-3.7+
            return
        yield tuple(res)
```

The latter code also works on python-2.7 and python-3.x < 3.7 but it's only required to catch the `StopIteration`s in python 3.7+

Comment: [In a generator function, the return statement is not allowed to include an expression_list. In that context, a bare return indicates that the generator is done and will cause StopIteration to be raised.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)

Secondly, if the test weren't there you'd have `res=[]` in an infinite loop. That would cause trouble for code doing `zip(*emptylist)`.

Comment: Rather than doing `if not iters: return None` why not do `if not args: return None` at the beginning of the function? That way, you avoid having to even attempt to compute `iters` if you have no arguments.

Comment: @YannVernier Thanks for the link. I always thought `return None` was acceptable in generator functions - so thank you for bringing that up!

Comment: That seems to be the case in Python 3.3 and later (setting the value attribute of the StopIteration). In 2.7 the return expression is just forbidden. We both learned something :)

Comment: Yup, I found that out too (and changed the comment). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: As of Python 3.7, [your code will not work because the `StopIteration` gets converted into a `RuntimeError`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/).

Comment: @Kevin I don't raise StopIterations so why shouldn't it work on 3.7? See also [this section of PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/#examples-of-breakage) which shows that `return` should still work.

Comment: @MSeifert: You are not using `return`.  You are calling `next()` and relying on it to raise `StopIteration` when it runs out of items.  In 3.7, that will get converted into a `RuntimeError` when it crosses the generator stack frame.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I should have read the examples more carefully. I don't have a Python-3.7 dev version installed so I had to guess a bit based on the information in PEP-479 - But I included a version that catches the `StopIteration`s that are raised by `next`.

Answer (score 4):

> Why the list comprehension doesn't need to catch a StopIteration

The whole *point* of this loop is for `next()` to raise a `StopIteration` and the list comprehension not to catch it. It's how this generator *exits*; the `while` loop is essentially endless, the condition it tests is stable.

That way the generator stops neatly when one of the inputs has been exhausted:

```
>>> g = myzip([1], [2, 3])
>>> next(g)
(1, 2)
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in myzip
StopIteration
```

The `StopIteration` exception was raised by the `next()` call on the first iterator in `iters`.

In essence, all that `while iters:` does is return `False` if you called `myzip()` with no inputs at all:

```
>>> list(myzip())
[]
```

Otherwise, it may as well use `while True:` for all the difference it makes.

Now, in Python 3, `map(iter, args)` returns an iterator, not a list. That object can only be iterated over once, but it is *not considered empty* and will always have a boolean value of *true*. That means that the second run through the `while iters:` loop, `iters` is true, but `[next(i) for i in iters]` iterates 0 times, `next()` is never called and the required `StopIteration` to exit the generator is never raised. That's why the author suggested `list(map(iter, args))` as a work-around, to capture the `map` iterator values into a list.

Comment: Why does having a `map(iters, args)` instead of `list(map(iters, args))` cause an infinite loop? And also, if I did `list(myzip([1],[2,3])`, does it cause the function to break out of its while loop when it sees a StopIteration?

Comment: @Dan: because the second iteration is then empty and `next()` is never called again. But the `while` condition is true forever; it's the `StopIteration` exception that's supposed to end the generator. So, yes; you can also use `[iter(i) for i in args]`.

Comment: I was thinking that the iterator wouldn't be exhausted, if for example `[next(i) for i in y]` where y is `[iter(1,2), iter(3,4)]` had only outputted [1,3] because you can still loop to get [2,4]. What I'm trying to say is I thought only when you reach StopIteration that the iterator is exhausted?

Comment: @Dan: the iterator is *never exhausted*. Raising a `StopIterator` simply exits the generator; and since that exception is the expected signal to end a generator, Python is fine with that.

Comment: @Dan: but in the case of `map(iters, args)` in Python 3, the iterator *would* be exhausted (after the first iteration of the `while` loop, and thus always produce `[]`, forever and ever. `StopIteration` is never raised and the generator never exits.